# How to handle signals when a widget has many child widgets

Tags: qt, pyqt, signals-slots

I am designing a game that includes a world map widget; this widget has 100+ region widgets as its children. There is also a separate information panel widget. When I click on a region, I want that information to be sent and displayed on the information panel. My thoughts so far give me 2 options:

1. Connect each of the 100+ regions to the information panel. This seems ugly to me as I feel like the information panel should only know about the world map widget, not its internal workings (such as children).
2. Connect each of the 100+ regions to the map widget, and then have the map
   send another signal to be picked up by other widgets in the game such as the information panel. This seems nicer as far as having independent widgets goes, but requires 2 signals instead of 1.

Is one of these methods preferable to the other? Or is there another solution I am missing entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to work for a company which made its own geospatial information system (GIS) product and we had this exact use case using Qt as well.

From my experience we would use option #2 as it encapsulated the details and relationships between the information panel (i.e. a *view*) and the world map (i.e. a *model*).

In the future maybe your world map will contain more than selectable *regions* and the information panel may not want to have to start knowing about all of the different *entities* in your world map to display them. So yes while #2 results in some additional signals it can be better from an encapsulation and expansion standpoint.

For example connect the information panel to a signal from your world map regarding a selected *entity* rather than a *region*. Sure a *region* **is** an *entity* and using *region* directly could work but again in the future maybe your world map will have selectable *buildings*, *markers*, *vehicles*, etc...

i.e.

```
connect( mapWidget, SIGNAL( selectedEntityChanged( MapEntity* ) ), 
         infoPanel, SLOT( onSelectedEntityChanged( MapEntity* ) ) );
```

This way your information panel could be designed to generically display information about an *entity*, again from which a *region* is derived. If you want to add say a *vehicle* to your map and make it so the information panel can display it, all you'll have to do is derive your *vehicle* from *entity* and you'll be good to go.

Great question welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't thinking about possible extensions in the future, but that makes perfect sense. It's worth a lot to code things in a way that prevents it from getting ugly down the road.

Comment: @TheBeardedTemplar Glad I could help. I updated the answer a bit but basically you'll want to make sure you have strong interfaces and/or abstract base classes so you can make your widgets work on generic types rather than very specific implements whenever possible. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that each `QObject` comes with a property system - a general purpose, Python-like key-value store. The keys are strings, and the values are variants. Since `QWidget` is a `QObject`, you can leverage that. Just by itself this makes `QSignalMapper` quite redundant.

You can also use the undocumented, but slightly faster [`userData` mechanism](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h.html#410) - it uses integer keys instead of string keys. The unique key ids are obtained through `registerUserData()`, with semantics otherwise identical to `QEvent::registerEventType`.